# array values into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have an array that looks like:

```
Array ( [0]  => 'overview' 
        [53] => 'PUBLIC' 
        [54] => '-friendsD' 
        [55] => 'XHTML' 
        [56] => '1.0' 
        [57] => 'Transitional' 
        [77] => 'People' );
```

How can I take those values and put them into MySQL with an `INSERT`? For example `INSERT INTO array_value VALUES ('$arrayvalues')`. For each array value is a new post into MySQL.

I tried this:

```
  <?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.mysiteexample.com/');
$array = explode(" ",$homepage);
foreach($array as $val) {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "111";
$password = "111";
$dbname = "111";
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
if ($val != " "){
$val = $val. " ";
    $query = "INSERT INTO `111` (word) VALUES ('$val')";

       $executeQuery = $conn->query($query) === TRUE;

    }

    if ($executeQuery === TRUE) {
        //echo "New record created successfully";
echo $val;
    } else {
        //echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
echo $val. " ";
    }}
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

This works to some extent. It produces many empty results how could it be filtered to have no empty posts. I tried the $val != " " but this didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried something? Show it!

Comment: Did you try the answer I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the array and build the query. Then execute it.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.mywebsite.com/');
$array = explode(" ",$homepage);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    $executeQuery;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if (!empty($array[$i])) {
            $executeQuery = $conn->query("INSERT INTO `yourTable` (yourField) VALUES ('" . $array[$i]  . "')");
        }
    }

    if ($executeQuery === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```